# Bytebuffer array() method not supported in Android below Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-ndk, bytebuffer

I’m working on a project where I want to send a byte buffer between Android SDK level and Android NDK level.

The recommended way seems to be to use a ByteBuffer using the allocateDirect() method i.e. on SDK level do:

```
ByteBuffer frameBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 10000 );
int frameSize = fillMyArrayMethod(frameBuf.array());
UseArrayInNdk(frameBuf);
```

Everything worked perfect on my ICS phone, however on my friends Android 2.3.3 version the code crashed.

Investigation revealed that it was the ByteBuffer’s array() method that threw UnsupportedOperationException on the 2.3.3 version phone.

Apparently this method is not supported in Android versions below Honeycomb.

So as I can’t get an array pointer to my buffer I’m now forced to make an additional put() for all data in my array before using it in my NDK, i.e. like this:

```
ByteBuffer frameBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 10000 );
Byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[10000];
int frameSize = fillMyArrayMethod(tmpBuf);

for (int i=0; i<frameSize; i++)
{
    frameBuf.put(i, tmpBuf[i]);
}
UseArrayInNdk(frameBuf);
```

So OK, to do it on Android Honeycomb and above the code is fine, but is there a smarter way to it on 2.3.3 and below to avoid the additional copying?

Answer (score 0):

The change in Dalvik implementation is that direct byte buffer was not backed by array before ICS. There is no guarantee that it will be possible to call array() in future versions. You can always check [hasArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#hasArray%28%29) before using a `ByteBuffer`. Even if you cannot use the array directly, the way you coded for ICS, you can always use a batch [put()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) method, you do not need to call it in a loop.

In conclusion, let me quote from the Android JNI tips page: [Depending on how direct byte buffer access is implemented in the VM, accessing the data from code written in Java can be very slow.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html)